# Matcher groupCount() and find() do not add up

Tags: java, regex

I want to split an input string into blocks starting with `\begin{<word>}` and ending with `\end{<word>}` where <word> can be "block", "vers" or "refr" and do addBlock() on each block. When trying this method on a string containing two of these blocks, `m.groupCount()` correctly returns 2, but `m.find()` returns false. How can this be? `m.group()` throws an exception.

```
private void addBlocks(String in) {
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\\\begin\\{(vers|refr|block)\\}.*\\\\end\\{(vers|refr|block)\\}");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(in);
    while (m.find()) {
        addBlock(m.group());
    }
}
```

Edit:
Yep, there were several things wrong there. Regex is a pain in the ass, it isn't very intuitive, and there is not that much sensible help online. Here is the code that finally worked:

```
private void addBlocks(String in) {
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\\\begin\{(block|vers|refr)\\}(.|$)*?\\\\end\\{(block|vers|refr)\\}", Pattern.DOTALL);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(in);
    while (m.find()) {
         addBlock(m.group());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, your code works for me, at least for this test call:

```
addBlocks("foo bar \\begin{vers}bla\\end{vers}foo bar baz \\begin{refr}bla2\\end{refr} bla");
```

However, your regular expression will call `addBlock()` at most once because of the greedy `*` quantifier. You might rather want to use the `*?` quantifier:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\\\begin\\{(vers|refr|block)\\}.*?\\\\end\\{(vers|refr|block)\\}");
```

With the `*?` quantifier you’ll get two matches for the above test call.

If there is no match on some input, then `m.find()` will correctly return `false` and `m.group()` will not be called (and thus won’t throw any `IllegalStateException`). Independent of the input string, `m.groupCount()` will always be 2 for your particular regular expression, as there are 2 capturing groups *in the pattern*.

Answer (score 0):

This will never give more than one result because of the .* which eats every character that is preceded by the closing tag.

groupCount() doesn't return the number of matches, but the *number of capturing groups*. Also explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2989061/2947592